# Moving a subsite to become the main site sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a client who is setting up a sharepoint file share and for some reason has setup the site as a subsite on the default central administration sire (port 6042) instead of on the site on port 80. Now the issue is that he would like external access to this site and wants it on port 80.

Is it possible to move the subsite's content (design of site etc) into the site located on port 80? i havent had much experience with sharepoint or iis and cannot find where these files are located or how to move these easily as i cannot export the subsite from administration panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, there are two ways to do that:

1. Backup the site collection that contains the content. Create a new
   site collection located on port 80 and restore the backup file to the
   new site is created.
   See how to backup/restore here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/backuprestore-of-sharepoint-2010-site-collection-using-power-shell/
2. Using powershell to export all the content from sub site. Create a new site located on port 80, deploy your Sharepoint branding or any
   features from sub site to the new site and import the content to the
   new site.